# Switching the ViewController with button doesn't shows the NavigationBar in second ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to create a page were you press the "Login" button(witch is located on NavigationBar, left item) and after is showing the second page(aka home page) were user can sign out. In the same time I want to remember that the user is logged in, using UserDefault.

Here is my AppDelegate file:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    theViewController(controllerIs: LoginPage())

    return true
}
fileprivate func theViewController(controllerIs: UIViewController) {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controllerIs)
}

}
```

The Login view:

```
import UIKit

class LoginPage: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .green
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogin))
}
@objc private func handleLogin() {

    let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    root?.present(SignOutPage(), animated: true, completion: {
        //some code here
    })


}
}
```

The Sign Out view:

```
import UIKit

class SignOutPage: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .yellow

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))

}
@objc private func handleSignOut() {
    let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    root?.present(LoginPage(), animated: true, completion: {
        //some code here
    })

}
}
```

The result is this:
[image]
and the sign out view
[image]
instead of
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
root?.present(SignOutPage(), animated: true, completion: {
    //some code here
})
```

you are presenting the SignOutPage view controller modally which will put it over the root view controller.

What you are wanting to do is to push it onto the navigate controller stack so you need something like this:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(SignOutPage(), animated: true)
```

In the same way when you sign out instead of presenting the view controller you want to pop the current one off the stack doing something like this:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

That will return the app back to the previous view controller (the login one).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things in going forward in navigation hierarchy.

1. **Navigation Stack** only follows in case of `pushViewController`. In case of `present` modally you need to initiate new navigation stack

   ```
   let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
   self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

***Where, viewController is the object of your new `UIViewController`.***

2. Rather than using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` each time you should use navigation stack( for push) and view controller( for present) as:

   ```
   // Push
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

   // Present Modally
   self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

***Where, `self` is your view controller's object and `viewController` is object of new `UIViewController`.***

---

**So, your `handleLogin()` on `LoginPage` will be like:**

```
// Push
@objc private func handleLogin() {
    guard let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignOutVC") as? SignOutPage else { return }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

// Pop
@objc private func handleLogin() {
    guard let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignOutVC") as? SignOutPage else { return }
    let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**And, `handleSignOut()` on `SignOutPage` will be like:**

```
// Push
@objc private func handleSignOut() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

// Pop
@objc private func handleSignOut() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

***NOTE: You need to set storyboard-identifier as:***

[image]